# Ruby create a specific array from range

Tags: ruby

I was wondering how can I generate the following array using ranges in ruby

```
["00","00","01","01","02", "02", ...... "10", "10"]
```

I want to repeat each element twice thats the part that I am looking an answer for. I can generate single elements as below

```
("00".."10").to_a
```

I know I can do this using loops etc but I am looking for a simpler one line code

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
("00".."10").flat_map { |x| [x, x] }
#=> ["00", "00", "01", "01", ..., "10", "10"]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
a = ("00".."10").to_a
a.zip(a).flatten
# ["00", "00", "01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "03", "04", "04", "05", "05", "06", "06", "07", "07", "08", "08", "09", "09", "10", "10"]
```